# Rsync, incremental file list output but no actual copying

Tags: bash, ubuntu, backup, rsync, pem

I'm running the following command, with the intention of recreating the contents of (sync) on the remote server.

```
sudo rsync -avrz /path/to/sync/ -e "ssh -i ../keys/my.pem user@xx.xx.xx.xx:/path/to/sync/"
```

However, when I run this I get a "sending incremental file list" output and a list of the files which should be copied.  Nothing actually gets written to the remote server.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
sudo rsync -avrz /path/to/sync/ -e "ssh -i ../keys/my.pem" user@xx.xx.xx.xx:/path/to/sync/
```

Note the place of the second " character. There is no remote address specified in the previous command.

Answer (score 1):

@Can does it right, but there is another way to go which might as well be considered.

Create a section in `/root/.ssh/config` containing the following:

```
Host mybackuptarget # or whatever you prefer
User user
Hostname xx.xx.xx.xx
IdentityFile /path/to/keys/my.pem
```

and execute

```
sudo rsync -avrz /path/to/sync/ mybackuptarget:/path/to/sync/
```

.